# Easy list with multi-language documents

Tags: easylist

For the shown MWE, the [easylist] package is working fine with the default language of the document which is set to "Arabic" language, however upon using other language "English", the bullets are correct but the indentation is lost.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,6]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,7]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,8]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,9]{label=$\bullet$}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt} 

\usepackage[at]{easylist}
        \ListProperties(
                Progressive*=3ex,
                Space=5pt,
                Space*=5pt,
                Style1*=\textbullet\ \ ,
                Style2*=\begin{normalfont}\begin{bfseries}\textendash\end{bfseries}\end{normalfont} \ \ ,
                Style3*=\textasteriskcentered\ \ ,
                Style4*=\textperiodcentered\ \ ,
                Style5*=\textbullet\ \ ,
                Style6*=\begin{normalfont}\begin{bfseries}\textendash\end{bfseries}\end{normalfont}\ \ ,
                Style7*=\textasteriskcentered\ \ ,
                Style8*=\textperiodcentered\ \ ,
                Hide1=1,
                Hide2=2,
                Hide3=3,
                Hide4=4,
                Hide5=5,
                Hide6=6,
                Hide7=7,
                Hide8=8 )
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu,multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}




\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 
\begin{easylist}
@ يبيسبسيبيسب
@@ سيبسيبسيبسيب
@@@ سيبسيبسيبسيبسيب
@@@@ سيبسيبسيبسيبسيب
@@@@@ سيبسيبسيبسيبسيبسيب
@@@@@@ سيبسيبيسبسيبسيبسيبسيب
\end{easylist}
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{easylist}
@ qwewqewqe
@@ qwewqewqe
@@@ qwewqewqe
@@@@ qwewqewqe
@@@@@ qwewqewqe
@@@@@@ qwewqewqe
\end{easylist}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Did you try to use `paracol`?

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat, I never heard about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\shapemode1
\begin{easylist}
@ qwewqewqe
@@ qwewqewqe
@@@ qwewqewqe
@@@@ qwewqewqe
@@@@@ qwewqewqe
@@@@@@ qwewqewqe
\end{easylist}
\end{otherlanguage}
```

The LuaTeX parameter `\shapemode` controls how `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` behave in bidi contexts, which are used by `easylist`. `babel` adds this parameter to some internal macros, including standard lists, but not to packages (`enumitem` relies on the LaTeX `\list`, so it works out the box).

By the way, don't use `\babelprovide` for languages supported in the standard way as class or package options, except if there is a reason to prefer not to load them.